# Count Facebook-users with a certain name

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I want to check a name with Facebook to display how many users are on Facebook (generally) with the same name. I'ld like to display this on my website.

I know that it's possible, I see on different websites this information:
+/- 14225 Zoltan's on Facebook (Position #4454)

But I have no idea were I can find a script for this. I searched everywere but couldn't find anything. Is there someone who can help me, please?

Comment: _Where_ do you see this information?

Comment: You can see @ http://tiny.cc/qf7i2w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most near results that you can using the Graph API is using-

> http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=jeroen&type=user

(needs a valid access_token)

Comment: Thanks. But if I try in Gralph API Explorer I get next result:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Jeroen Knockaert", 
      "id": "1425871011"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Jeroen Edig", 
      "id": "1738591634"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Jeroen Elings", 
      "id": "819070180"
    }, 
   etc.

But how can I count those results? Any idea?

Comment: Which platform are you using? Just count the no. of objects of this JSON. PS. you can accept the answer if that helped!

Comment: I'm always using PHP. This is the first time using Graph API. And I can't find a lot about it. Is it possible to connect with PHP? That'll be much easier for myself if possible:p PS answer accepted ofcourse, thank you!

Comment: Yes of course, search for this, you'll definitely get many links how to get the access token, then you can simply use curl/facebook-sdk to `\GET``http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=jeroen&type=user&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` and you'll get the results

Comment: $json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=user&q=jeroen&access_token=TOKEN_Key');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$data = $data['data'];
echo count($data); It works, it count the results. But I only get the first 25 results.. Why a limit of 25 results? Same as I get in browser

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#606) LIMIT value of 9999 exceeds allowed maximum of 5000.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 606
   }
} 

With a limit value of 5000 I'm afraid it's not my solution :(

Comment: As I said, that's what you can get using the API (that's for sure) - regarding 5000 limit, yes that's the limit by facebook - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10422248/1343690